# how to "--setopt=protected_multilib=false -y" without yum install

Tags: centos, yum

We have a client who needs an installation on a VM with no connection to the internet. Usually I would've used a chef client who will preform command lines such as:

`yum install glibc.i686 --setopt=protected_multilib=false -y`

Since the client has no internet yum (and chef) can not do their magic.

I was able to install the programs such as "glibc.i686" without yum, but was unable to find how to configure `setopt=protected_multilib=false` (Also after a long google time, and searching serverfault).

How can I preform this command manually? Is this addition crucial?

Comment: Do you know what it does?

Comment: I am not sure, from my understanding this will allow a 32-bit program work on a 86_64X arch (I tried to google it). Although I am not sure about this. Although I don't know what it is I wanted to implement it to make sure that the client will not have any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rear use case but quite used in Oracle or CAD installations.
You can configure `protected_multilib=0` in your yum.conf.
According to the manual:

```
          protected_multilib Either `1' or `0'. This tells yum whether or not it should perform a check to make sure that multilib packages are the same version. For example, if this option is off (rpm
          behaviour)  pkgA-1.x86_64  and  pkgA-2.i386  can  be installed at the same time. However this is very rarely desired.  Install only packages, like the kernel, are exempt from this check.  The
          default is `1'.
```